# Changes made to argv in main() are lost in applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: program-entry-point, argv

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    strncpy(argv[1], "fookBar", 7);

    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    NSArray *args = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];


}
```

the args array in applicationDidFinishLaunching doesnt show the chages made to argv[1] in main. ?. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSApplicationMain)

"NSApplicationMain itself ignores the argc and argv arguments. Instead, Cocoa gets its arguments indirectly via _NSGetArgv, _NSGetArgc, and _NSGetEnviron (see )."

Thats the reason why even when you make changes to the argv in main, it does not reflect in applicationDidFinishLaunching